# Is it safe to cast atomic<T> to T

Tags: c++, atomic, futex

I have two questions:

1. In the general case is it safe to use an atomic as a T and switch between them interchangeably?
2. In the case of a futex is it safe to do the cast?

I am aware that performing atomic operations on non-atomic types is undefined behaviour but I cannot find an answer for the reverse. For example, this which compiles and executes as expected:

```
std::atomic_int foo = 5;
int* bar = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&foo);
(*bar)++;
std::cout << (*bar) << std::endl;
```

As to the second question, the Linux manpage says in the FUTEX_WAIT operation

> The load of the
> value of the futex word is an atomic memory access (i.e.,
> using atomic machine instructions of the respective
> architecture).  This load, the comparison with the
> expected value, and starting to sleep are performed
> atomically and totally ordered with respect to other futex
> operations on the same futex word.

So is the following code safe?

```
std::atomic_int32_t val = 0;
syscall(SYS_futex, reinterpret_cast<int*>(&val), FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, nullptr);
```

Comment: Looks like blatant UB.

Comment: The reason why you haven't found an answer for the reverse is pretty simple: most folks just atomically load or store a regular T value into the atomic T as required.  operator T and operator = are your friends.  The cost of stacking a T is usually small compared to the cost of introducing Unknown Behavior.

Comment: Re: `(*bar)++` -- presumably the goal here is to do a non-atomic increment. If that's acceptable, then just use a non-atomic object. If you're going to bypass atomicity, being atomic is pointless.

Comment: No, but I've seen some professional libraries do it to mix C++ atomics and futexes together.. It's still UB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In the general case is it safe to use an atomic as a T and switch between them interchangeably?

Not with `reinterpret_cast`. `reinterpret_cast` is only safe in the cases where it is explicitly listed as such, and this is not one.

You can however turn a `T` temporarily into an atomic object with `std::atomic_ref`.

> In the case of a futex is it safe to do the cast?

No.

However, `std::atomic_ref` has a similar API to `std::atomic`, including `wait`.